# powershell script to get sql job result using Get-SqlAgentJobHistory

Tags: powershell

This powershell command will show me failed SQL Server jobs on PADB1 since yesterday. But some jobs may have been fixed since then, and some may have ran 3 days ago:

> Get-SqlAgentJobHistory -ServerInstance "PADB1" -Since Yesterday
> -Outcome Failed

Is there a way to simply show the last result of all jobs, no matter when ran?

Comment: Get-SqlAgentJobHistory -ServerInstance "PADB1" -StartRunDate [DateTime]::Parse( '4/1/2023')

Comment: That is still time dependent. Looking for failed jobs whether ran last night or last week.

Comment: If '-Since Yesterday' is removed, it returns failed events from months ago even if it has since passed.

Comment: You need to Group the jobs by job number and then get the latest.  Normally what is done is to get all jobs and sort by date descending so latest date is first.  Then group by job ID.  Finally get first item from each group which is the latest date.

Comment: This gives the last outcome for jobs in pretty formatted columns:
Get-SqlAgentJob -ServerInstance "PADB1" | Format-Table -Property @{ L='Server';e='OriginatingServer'; width = 15 }, @{ L='Job Name';e='Name'; width = 50 }, @{ L='Enabled';e='IsEnabled'}, @{ L='Outcome';e='LastRunOutcome'}, @{e='LastRunDate'; width = 21}, @{ L='Duration';e='LastRunDuration'}